# SAT Math question about polynomials

Tags: polynomials

The question is thus:
[image]

My issue is: As far as I can tell, none of these options work. I can see that it needs to have (x+5)(x-1) as factors, but neither (x-2) nor (x+2) will create a polynomial that passes through the given points.

Comment: The question is wrong and you are correct.

Comment: SAT review books are notorious for having typos. You are correct that $(x+5)$ and $(x-1)$ must divide the polynomial, and none of the given options work.

Answer (score 3):

They asked which one could be the polynomial, implying that it still might not correct. However, by the fact that $-5$ and $1$ are zeros of the polynomial, we can conclude immediately that only D could work (the others definitely cannot work).

In general, I can tell you that the polynomial passing though those points is of the form:
P(x)=a(x+5)(x-1)(x-r)

For some real number $r$ and some nonzero constant $a$.

Edit: Why doesn't C work? If you notice, the other points have $y$ values that are positive, then negative, this implies that the third solution must lie between those values (i.e., within $(-3,-1)$), which precludes option C.

Comment: C or D, I think

Comment: `only D could work` No, **C** could work as well, just like the OP hinted.

Comment: C does not work because of of sign pattern around solutions and intermediate points (I failed to catch/mention that).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Fair enough!

Comment: If this is really the way the problem is meant to be interpreted, I think it's a terrible question... none of the options "could work" because you can verify by plugging in the points that they do not work! But +1 for figuring out what the College Board is looking for.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how any of the options are possible? They all fail for at least one of the given points...

Comment: I concur with kccu that it's a terrible question. Reminds me of all those 'find the sequence' questions where they only give you the first few terms and realistically the other terms could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Two roots are given, which limits the potential answers to **C** or **D**. Then the $3^{rd}$ root lies in the interval $(-3,-1)$ since the polynomial changes sign between those, which excludes option **C**.

Comment: This isn't really a hint. I feel like it makes little sense to label it as one

Comment: Option D is also excluded by the fact that x = -3 does not evaluate to 4.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Point taken, edited accordingly. It *did* start out as a hint, but went beyond that.

Comment: The proper way to find $P$ is to use finite differences, I may work that as a 2nd answer.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Right, of course. But there is also a time constraint in multiple choice tests.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how any of the options are possible? They all fail for at least one of the given points...

Comment: @mrnovice None of them are possible. People here are reaching and making guesses about what the question author might have had in mind as "the right tools to use", tbh

Comment: @StellaBiderman But what could they have had in mind? The only thing I can think of is that there is a typo in the given points. What else could it be?

Comment: @mrnovice The question is "*P(x)* ***could*** *equal*". I read that as: *if one were to take a quick guess, which option would make most sense*? It does not mean that the option must in fact satisfy the conditions (which, indeed, none of them does).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the related question of which cubic actually goes through those 4 points (none of the given polynomials actually do).

Let's exploit what we already know: $-5$ and $1$ are zeros of $P(x)$. Therefore, we know that $P$ has the form:

$P(x)=a(x+5)(x-1)(x-r)$

exploiting the other given points, we find that:

$P(-3)=4=a(-3+5)(-3-1)(-3-r)$

$4=-8a(-r-3)$

$1=2a(r+3)$ (pull factor of $-1$ out of binomial)

and

$P(-1)=-3=a(-1+5)(-1-1)(-1-r)$

$-3=-8a(-1-r)$

$-3=8a(r+1)$

This gives us a (non-linear) system of 2 equations and 2 unknowns, we proceed by substitution. Solve the first equation for $a$ in terms of $r$.

$2a=\dfrac{1}{r+3}$

$a=\dfrac{1}{2(r+3)}$

Substitute into the second equation.

$-3=8\left(\dfrac{1}{2(r+3)}\right)(r+1)$

$-3=\dfrac{4(r+1)}{r+3}$

$-3(r+3)=4(r+1)$

$-3r-9=4r+4$

$-13=7r$

$r=\frac{-13}{7}$

Substitute for $r$ in first equation and solve for $a$.

$1=2a(\frac{-13}{7}+3)$

$1=2a(\frac{8}{7})$

$1=\frac{16}{7}a$

$a=\frac{7}{16}$

Therefore, $P$ is actually

$P(x)=\frac{7}{16}(x+5)(x+\frac{13}{7})(x-1)$

Comment: If I've made an error, I can't seem to find it. Might want to double check your work (I just double checked mine). As far as I can tell, our equations aren't equivalent.

Comment: Found it! I had $4=8a(r+3)$ somehow went to $1=4a(r+3)$ instead of $1=2a(r+3)$. Fixed, and followed the error through correcting things. Mathematics is easy, arithmetic is hard.